# How can I get all the unique categories within my dataframe using python?

Tags: python, pandas

im new to python and trying to work with dataframes manipulation:

I have a df with unique categories:
I am unable to paste the dataframe because I use Spyder IDE and it is not interactive does not display all fields.

My input to get all these unique categories within a dataframe:

```
uc =[]
for i in df['Category']:
    if i[0] not in df['Category']:
        uc.append(i[0])
print(uc)
```

But when I use this script, I only receive the first letters of these categories:

Output:

```
['F', 'P', 'N', 'F', 'L', 'T', 'W', 'S', 'W', 'B', 'S', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'B', 'T', 'B', 'L', 'S', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'N', 'P', 'H', 'T', 'L', 'T', 'S', 'E', 'P', 'N', 'T', 'L', 'P', 'L', 'W', 'F', 'N', 'L', 'N', 'L', 'F', 'F', 'N', 'T', 'P', 'L', 'B', 'W', 'L', 'W', 'F', 'F', 'H', 'T', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'N', 'G', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'F', 'N', 'F', 'L', 'N', 'P', 'F', 'B', 'B', 'S', 'F', 'P', 'F', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'B', 'P', 'B', 'B', 'L', 'B', 'F', 'P', 'P', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'B', 'P', 'T', 'P', 'P', 'N', 'G', 'S', 'G', 'F', 'G', 'F', 'T', 'S', 'P', 'F', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'G', 'C', 'F', 'C', 'F', 'B', 'G', 'C', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'P', 'G', 'S', 'D', 'P', 'G', 'F', 'L', 'C', 'G', 'P', 'S', 'B', 'P', 'T', 'T', 'L', 'M', 'F', 'T', 'P', 'C', 'F', 'B', 'M', 'G', 'C', 'P', 'T', 'L', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'T', 'P', 'C', 'G', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'S', 'B', 'M', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'T', 'H', 'B', 'N', 'F', 'A', 'T', 'E', 'M', 'L', 'G', 'P', 'B', 'L', 'N', 'S', 'G', 'G', 'F', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'F', 'T', 'G', 'P', 'G', 'C', 'G', 'G', 'G', 'F', 'T', 'T', 'L', 'F', 'S', 'T', 'F', 'F', 'G', 'G', 'L', 'M', 'T', 'L', 'F', 'B', 'A', 'F', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'B', 'T', 'F', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'P', 'V', 'M', 'S', 'F', 'C', 'B', 'N', 'M', 'W', 'B', 'F', 'B', 'F', 'F', 'M', 'L']
```

How do I change my script to reveive unique categories within a dataframe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with

```
 df['Category'].unique()
```

Answer (score 4):

`print(df['Category'].unique())` see what you get.

Also, `i[0]` is retrieving the first char of a string value in the df['Category'].

also, if you are new to pandas, you MUST abandon the old habit of `for` loop. And always `type()` your result to obtain better understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this?

```
uc = set(df['Category'])
```

This will create a set containing the unique values of 'Category'